# Why the function f(x) is not a probability density function(PDF)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I saw this example but I can't understand why its's not PDF.

Exmaple:
Suppose $ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} c\left(1-x^{2}\right) & \text { if }-2 \leq x \leq 2 \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. } \end{array}\right. $, Is there a value of  c for which $f(x)$ is a probability density function? Why or why not?

Solution: This cannot be a probability density function. If $ c=0 $, then it does not integrate 1 . For any $ c \neq 0 $, there is an interval in $ -2 \leq x \leq 2 $ over which the integral is negative, and therefore does not represent a probability over this interval.

I understand that $c$ shouldn't equal $0$ and the outcome in the first case shouldn't be negative, right?
so what if $c$ is negative, then the outcome will be positive for $-2 \leq x \leq 2$. Or is there otherway to show that with integral ? since it should be 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c>0$ then $f$ is negative in $[-2,2] \setminus [-1,1]$. If $c<0$ then $f$ is negative in $(-1,1)$. Either way it is negative somewhere.

The "gotcha" part of this question is that $\int_{-2}^2 1-x^2 dx=-4/3 \neq 0$, so the students not paying careful attention are expected to say that if $c=-3/4$ then you have a PDF. But because this $f$ isn't nonnegative, it is still not a PDF.

Comment: so the idea here is it look for some value which make $f$ negative, since the probability should be between $[0,1]$ right?, and if we can't find such a value then we can just calculate $c$ for the $PDF$ ?

Comment: The probability *density* is in $[0,\infty)$ everywhere. The density can exceed $1$, even though *probabilities* are always in $[0,1]$.

Comment: ah that's right, thanks!

Comment: I have another example: $f(x) = 
c(3x − x^2)$ if $0 ≤ x ≤ 2$. 0 otherwise. So if $c<0$ with $x=2$ we get $-1\dot(2)=-2$, but the function is PDF, why?

Comment: @MR.-c With that one, with $c>0$ it's nonnegative everywhere. The fact that $c<0$ isn't OK is no problem.

Comment: when we solve the integral and find $c$, it can be any value in $\mathcal{R}$ right? or are there some restrication?

Comment: @MR.-c It can be anything, yeah.